# Importing AD attributes from CSV using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Im new to PowerShell and I'm attempting to update AD attributes using PowerShell from a .csv file

below are the rows in my csv file and what attributes I'm trying to update

Department  > Department

Division > Division

Service > info

EmployeeFullname    (using to identify the object)

LineMangerFullname  > manager

CostCentre  > departmentNumber

JobTitle > title

So far i've only been able to update the Department, Division , Title (Job Title) & Manager attributes in Active Directory

I am using the script below which updates these attributes successfully

```
$Users = Import-CSV C:\Users\user\Documents\CurrentWork\userlist.csv

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -property displayname | where {$_.displayname -eq $User.EmployeeFullName} | Set-ADUser -department $User.Department -Division $User.Division -Title $User.JobTitle -Manager $User.LineMangerFullname
}
```

however when adding `info` and `departmentNumber` to the script (below), it fails with:

> ```
> "parameter name 'info' is ambiguous" and A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'departmentNumber'
> ```

```
$Users = Import-CSV C:\Users\user\Documents\CurrentWork\userlist.csv

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -property displayname | where {$_.displayname -eq $User.EmployeeFullName} | Set-ADUser -department $User.Department -Division $User.Division -Title $User.JobTitle -Manager $User.LineMangerFullname -info $User.Service -departmentNumber $User.'Cost Centre'
}
```

does anyone know what im doing wrong or how I can get these to update please and also how i can export the results to see if the update is successful? really stuck here

Comment: The `Manager` property should be given as `DistinguishedName`, `GUID`, `SID` or `SamAccountName`. Is your `LineMangerFullname` in that format? If not, you will first have to retrieve that with a `Get-ADUser` cmdlet

Comment: the "LineManagerFullname" format is Firstname Lastname e.g. joe bloggs

Comment: Then you have to get the SamAccountName or DistinguishedName for that manager by using `$managerDN = (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq "$($User.LineMangerFullname)).DistinguishedName` and use that for the `-Manager` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set-ADUser` does not expose *all possible AD schema attributes* as parameters, only a limited set of common user attributes - and the `info` attributes (or "Notes" as it's displayed in some tools) is **not** one of the ones it has parameters for.

To set the value of a property that doesn't have a corresponding parameter, use the `-Replace` or `-Add` parameter(s), by passing a hashtable that describes the update:

```
... |Set-ADUser -Replace @{ info = "new info value" }
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented, The `Manager` property can only be one of `DistinguishedName, GUID, SID or SamAccountName` for Set-AccountName. Apparently, the CSV does not contain any of that and `$User.LineMangerFullname` contains the full First and Lastname of the manager.

For that, you need to use another `Get-ADUser` call to retrieve a valid property from that manager.

Next, as Mathias R. Jessen already pointed out in his [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66175538/9898643), not all attributes are **directly** available in the parameters of Set-ADUser, so for some you will have to use `-Replace @{property = value}` syntax.

Finally, I'd recommend using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on cmdlets that potentially can take a lot of parameters to make the code clean/maintainable.

Try

```
$Users = Import-CSV C:\Users\user\Documents\CurrentWork\userlist.csv

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($User.EmployeeFullName)'" -Properties DisplayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($adUser) {
        # set up a Splatting Hashtable for the Set-ADUser cmdlet
        $userParams = @{
            Department = $User.Department
            Division   = $User.Division
            Title      = $User.JobTitle
        }
        $manager = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq "$($User.LineMangerFullname) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        # if we did find a manager, add property 'Manager' to the Hashtable
        if ($manager) { $userParams['Manager'] = $manager.DistinguishedName }

        # use the Hash to splat all known parameters to Set-ADUser
        $adUser | Set-ADUser $userParams
        # next , update the attributes that have no direct parameter in Set-ADUser
        $adUser | Set-ADUser -Replace @{ info = $User.Service; departmentNumber = $User.'Cost Centre' }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User $($User.EmployeeFullName) could not be found"
    }
}
```