# Updating Active Directory Manager Attribute from .csv Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm not so good at PowerShell. I have this script which worked before that I've have used to update the manager attribute in Active Directory, however, now after just replacing the file its no longer working

```html
$Users = Import-CSV C:\Documents\Managers.csv
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
   $user= Get-ADUser -Filter "displayname -eq '$($Users.EmployeeFullName)'"|select -ExpandProperty samaccountname
   $manager=Get-ADUser -Filter "displayname -eq '$($Users.'Line Manager Fullname')'"|select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @{manager=$manager}
}
```

when running the script it returns:

```html
Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:6 char:22
+ Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @{manager=$manager}
+                      ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

the "EmployeeFullName" and "Line Manager FullName" format in the .csv is set as i.e. joe bloggs, see below CSV file example.

```
EmployeeFullname   Line Manager Fullname 
----------------   ---------------------
Kieran Rhodes      Tracey Barley    
Lewis Pontin       Tracey Barley
Lizzy Wilks        Rodney Bennett
```

I also noticed if I remove and try to retype "$Users.EmployeeFullName" it no longer picks up the "EmployeeFullName" from the csv file.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here please?

Comment: Inside the loop you are referencing `$Users` when it should be your iteration variable, `$User`.  The way you have it the properties are unrolling and its probably messing up the `Get-ADUser` command resulting in a null value being used in `Set-ADUser`'s `-Identity` argument.

Comment: so like below? I tried that but returns "the search filter cannot be recognised"

$Users = Import-CSV C:\Documents\Managers.csv
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
   $user= Get-ADUser -Filter "displayname -eq '$($User.EmployeeFullName)'"|select -ExpandProperty samaccountname
   $manager=Get-ADUser -Filter "displayname -eq '$($User.'Line Manager Fullname')'"|select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @{manager=$manager}
}

Comment: Sorry don't want to read in comment format, but I posted an answer below to illustrate.  It would also help if I had a sample of the csv content. I may be able to optimize further.

Comment: thanks, below is the format of the csv file e.g.

EmployeeFullname Line Manager FullName
Kieran Rhodes Tracey Barley
Lizzy Wilks Rodney Bennett

so i.e. 2 rows 1 for "EmployeeFullname" and 1 for  "Line Manager FullName"

Comment: I reworded the question, but I think the samples below are already sufficient.  I was just surprised at the column names.  At any rate, drop another comment if anything.

Comment: Could be just me, but didn't I answer that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66260741/9898643) already?

Answer (score 2):

Below would be an example:

```
$Users = Import-CSV C:\Documents\Managers.csv
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
   $user    = Get-ADUser -Filter "displayname -eq '$($User.EmployeeFullName)'"
   $manager = (Get-ADUser -Filter "displayname -eq '$($User.'Line Manager Fullname')'").DistinguishedName

Set-ADUser -Identity $User -Replace @{manager=$manager}
}
```

Note: you don't need to dig down to the samAccountName property because `Set-ADUser` will take the full fidelity object for the `-Identity` argument.  You also don't need to use `Select... -ExpandProperty` you can just parenthetically dot reference the distinguishedName property.

Also you can use the instancing capability in the AD cmdlets:

```
$Users = Import-CSV C:\Documents\Managers.csv
ForEach ( $User in $Users )
{
   $User    = Get-ADUser -Filter "displayname -eq '$($User.EmployeeFullName)'" -Properties Manager
   $Manager = (Get-ADUser -Filter "displayname -eq '$($User.'Line Manager Fullname')'").DistinguishedName

   $User.Manager = $Manager
   Set-ADUser -Instance $User 
}
```

In this case you call back the Manager property set it with a simple assignment statement than give the `$User` variable as the argument to the `-Instance` parameter of `Set-ADUser`